# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Not Opening

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am build an application with Twitter Bootstrap and Thymeleaf (Java / Spring). I cannot get the dropdown menu with bootstrap 3 to open, even when I copy the code from there examples.

Oddly it seems to work is JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w5bq2L65/

Here is the HTML that is being generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
    <title>Parameter Manager</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="title" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">POS Parameter Manager</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- page content -->

        <section>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Parameters can be found here</p>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- common scripts -->
    <script type="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its being included. <script type="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: If it works in the fiddle it might mean that you have some style issues with either custom css or theme css. I would check if the `<header>` or any parent element of the `.dropdown` has `overflow: hidden;`, this would prevent the dropdown menu from showing

Comment: I don't have any custom css at the moment. Only thing I can think of is something weird is going on with Thymeleaf generating HTML.

Comment: You need to [validate](https://html5.validator.nu/) your markup and check your console for errors because its not `type="javascript` it's `type="application/javascript"`and your jQuery CDN link is broken.

Comment: Ahhhh that fixed it!